# Return Chromium OS install to Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, chromium

I'm new to this site (though I've lurked and used a lot of answers on here before) and I have a question that no amount of Googling around seems to be able to answer.

So, I recently installed Chromium OS to my Lenovo T431s ThinkPad. I wiped the hard drive, including my Windows installation (because I hate Windows), with the intention of never going back to it and just using Chromium OS/Ubuntu.

Chromium OS is great and I like the OS a lot, but there are some minor issues that annoy me (Flash is wonky -- it works, but sporadically, I can't setup Google Docs to work offline, I can't watch Netflix, etc.) and I want to switch back to an Ubuntu 14.04 install.

The problem is that I can't find any instructions on how to do this. I've tried making a bootable USB with Ubuntu 14.04 and booting from that, but Chromium OS evidently doesn't have a way to set the boot order to boot from said USB drive, or at the very least it won't allow this drive to be booted because it isn't signed by Google. I'm not sure which, but the point is I can't boot from my USB drive.

I've looked around and found Ubuntu installation instructions specific to Chrome OS devices (NOT Chromium OS) such as ChrUbuntu, but none of these work for me because I can't enable Developer Mode like Chrome OS devices can (or at least I haven't yet found a way to do that).

I've also tried going into the shell in Chromium and dd'ing the Ubuntu image from the USB drive to my computer's actual hard drive, but that didn't seem to work, either.

So, can anyone help me out? I'm kind of desperate to get back to Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be you don't have a valid bootable usb stick . . have you tried http://www.pendrivelinux.com/

Comment: This is exactly what the problem was. I got it figured out and all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

turn off the computer, then turn it back on and press F12 to bring up the boot menu.  That should permit your computer to boot to alternate media such as an ubuntu live CD or USB.  If it does not boot to that media, you should consider the possibility the media itself is bad or that the ubuntu boot image on that media is corrupt.

To be clear, CHROME has nothing to do with it.  At the time of the boot menu, chrome hasn't even been read yet.  The computer's boot state is in it's native form, unaware, so to speak, of the operating system on the hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've tried this before too and it didn't work. I was able to get into the BIOS and set it so that the computer would first boot from the USB drive, but it seemed to always skip that and go straight into Chromium OS as soon as I exit the BIOS.

I've also tried some different USB drives and some different Ubuntu images, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It shouldn't be this complicated, but if nothing else works you can always watch this video in order to physically remove the hard drive from the computer, and with the hard drive first removed, turn the machine back on and repeat the previous steps to make sure you are doing everything right to make it boot to the USB drive.  If it boots then all you need to do to wipe the hard drive is to connect the hard drive to the computer using a usb-to-sata drive adapter and while it is connected use gparted or disk utility to wipe it.  http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/videos/pd027065

Comment: I guess it wasn't anywhere near that complicated! It turns out I was using the wrong kind of Ubuntu image for the live USB. I got it all figured out and it's working and installing right now. Thanks for the help! :D